How to properly test lambdas locally, regarding unit test and quick debug issues before having to go through the DEV pipeline?

Summary: we want to properly test out lambdas locally. With this, we want to test out code without having to go through the pipeline on every single change.

Been searching around stackoverlow to try to understand what is the overall consensus on testing lambdas.
While we will always have a dev environment where we have real code with real resources, and where we can properly do manual tests even, it would be great to be able to test quick changes locally, before going through the ordeal of running the dev pipeline.

I was thinking about using localstack (which has a pay wall) or moto for the local unit tests
this way we could pretty much run the code with proper integration with mocked components
not only we could do quick tests, we could also do unit and integration tests

Now, to run local unit tests with lambdas I'm guessing we have to have a docker environment - from what I read in other questions, Moto supports docker.
Then, after running the tests and everything checking out, life would continue and the pipeline would run these tests and others, both for DEV and QA, and even PROD.
Is this something that has logic?

Some of this depends on what your Lambda functions actually do. If they need to connect to other services like SQS, SES, SNS, etc.. then it may be worth using something like localstack. If your functions don't need all that, then I highly recommend designing your Lambda functions in such a way that the hander methods simply pass event data to other functions, at which point your other functions are just basic Python/Java/NodeJS whatever functions that you can unit test like any other code.
